# Does macOS have a command to retrieve detailed CPU information like /proc/cpuinfo on Linux?

Tags: mac, command-line, cpu, darwin

Linux has a command to retrieve detailed CPU information using `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. Using this command, users can get CPU and CPU's core information like below.

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7267U CPU @ 3.10GHz
stepping    : 9
cpu MHz     : 3096.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti retpoline fsgsbase avx2 invpcid rdseed flush_l1d
bogomips    : 6192.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 142
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7267U CPU @ 3.10GHz
stepping    : 9
cpu MHz     : 3096.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc unfair_spinlock eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti retpoline fsgsbase avx2 invpcid rdseed flush_l1d
bogomips    : 6192.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Does macOS/OS X have a command to retrieve detailed CPU and CPU cores information equal to Linux `/proc/cpuinfo`? I really want to know a CLI command to retrieve the Mac's CPU core ID.

I tried `sysctl machdep.cpu`, but it didn't retrieve CPU core ID.

Comment: Related [Use OSX terminal to find out the CPU instructions set (AVX, SSE and such)](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/341525) & possible duplicate of [How to see which CPU is on the current macine?](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/85605)

Answer (score 72):

The Terminal command `sysctl` might be what you're looking for, in particular `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu`:

```
[my_mac:~] admin% sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu
machdep.cpu.max_basic: 22
machdep.cpu.max_ext: 2147483656
machdep.cpu.vendor: GenuineIntel
machdep.cpu.brand_string: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8210Y CPU @ 1.60GHz
machdep.cpu.family: 6
machdep.cpu.model: 142
machdep.cpu.extmodel: 8
machdep.cpu.extfamily: 0
.
.
.

machdep.cpu.core_count: 2
machdep.cpu.thread_count: 4
machdep.cpu.tsc_ccc.numerator: 134
machdep.cpu.tsc_ccc.denominator: 2
```

Info gleaned from [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2012/04/28/get-extended-cpu-information-from-the-command-line/).

Comment: I think most people might be just looking for the number of cores. The lines you are looking for are `machdep.cpu.core_count` and `machdep.cpu.thread_count`. Note that the thread count might be greater than the core count. Look up "hyperthreading" for Intel CPUs and "simultaneous multithreading" for AMD.

Comment: You can also use `sysctl -a machdep.cpu` instead of piping it to `grep`. (I do see this piped to `grep` often. Maybe this only works on new versions of macOS?)

Comment: It seems that `VirtualBox` really uses `machdep.cpu.thread_count` to show the maximum amount of Processors (the _CPUs value_ ) to define a new/edit VirtualMachine. It when macOS is the Host and other OS is the guest

Comment: $ sysctl machdep.cpu.brand_string

Comment: sysctl                                   
usage: sysctl [-bdehiNnoqx] name[=value] ...
       sysctl [-bdehNnoqx] -a

Answer (score 8):

If you go to the Apple menu item and under that is the option "About This Mac". Select that and when the pane shown below appears notice the buttons on the bottom.

[image]

The pane itself gives you some info but click on the System Report button. This opens a large pane where you can select specfic items to get info about. Click on an item in the left part of the pane and it tells you info about that item.

[image]

Comment: The CLI/Terminal equivalent is: 
`system_profiler SPHardwareDataType`

Comment: This is not a good idea. 1. did not use `command line`; 2. can not get details of the `CPU` version, such as `i7-8700B` instead of `i7`.